# XPATH conditional exclusion

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I have a html fragment that looks like the following;

```
<div class="sideBar">
 <ul>
   <li class="test testlist">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="test testlist"><div>sub test1</div></li>
      <li class="test testlist"><div>sub test2</div></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="test testlist"><div>test 2</div></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I need to get node list number two containing text "test 2", but when I try the following;

```
//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]//li[@class=\"test testlist\"])[2]//div
```

It returns node;

```
 <li class="test testlist"><div>sub test2</div></li>
```

How would I go about returning node please;

```
 <li class="test testlist"><div>test 2</div></li>
```

Many thanks,

C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the rule should be to get node with text "test 2".
First of all your xpath has a wrong parenthesis (copy past error):

```
//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]//li[@class=\"test testlist\"] -->)<-- [2]//div
```

There are two interpretation:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]//li[@class='test testlist'][2]//div"
```

Which will select all li (with class test testlis) descendant to the div which on second position to the parent.
Or:

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]//li[@class='test testlist'])[2]//div
```

Which will select the the second  li (with class test testlis) of the three found.

Both is not what you like to have. Therefore try:

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]//li[@class='test testlist'][2])[2]//div
```

The second of the two on position two.
Or best(in my view):

```
//div[contains(@class, 'sideBar')]/ul/li[@class='test testlist'][2]//div"
```

The second li in the first direct child ul of the div .